# Setting a framerate of a video created from images with ffmpeg (slowing down)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm making a video using ffmpeg & multiple images with this command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.png v.mpg
```

The video is made, but plays very fast. Can I slow it down a bit? (double duration nearly)
If possible set the speed while creation itself please.

I also need to add an audio "a.wav" to the video being made, possibly in the same command. Is that possible?

Please give me the commands
Thanks

When I use this command, below is the error I get:

```
ffmpeg -r 12 -i pic\s%d.png -i rmt.wav -shortest -r 25 v.mpg



FFmpeg version SVN-r16573, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
configuration: --extra-cflags=-fno-common --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-avisynth --enable-swscale --enable-gpl
libavutil     49.12. 0 / 49.12. 0
libavcodec    52.10. 0 / 52.10. 0
libavformat   52.23. 1 / 52.23. 1
libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
libswscale     0. 6. 1 /  0. 6. 1
built on Jan 13 2009 02:57:09, gcc: 4.2.4
Input #0, image2, from 'pic\s%d.png':
Duration: 00:03:53.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1366x768, 12.00 tb(r)
Input #1, wav, from 'rmt.wav':
Duration: 00:12:16.19, bitrate: 64 kb/s
Stream #1.0: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 1366x768, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25.00 tb(c)
Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Stream #1.0 -> #0.1
[mp2 @ 0x1738390]Sampling rate 8000 is not allowed in mp2
Error while opening codec for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A default frame rate of 25 is applied to input images if you do not declare an input frame rate. You can set the frame rate by using `-framerate` as an input option, such as:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%d.png v.mpg
```

The output will inherit this same frame rate. You can also set a frame rate for the input and output separately, but ffmpeg will simply copy or duplicate frames to compensate for the difference. One reason to do this is that MPEG1/2 does not support arbitrary frame rates.

This example will use an input frame rate of 12, about half of default 25, and output at 25. Frames will be duplicated by ffmpeg to reach 25:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 12 -i img%d.png -r 25 v.mpg
```

Video quality can be controlled with `-qscale:v`, which for mpeg* video is a linear scale of 1-31 where 1 is the highest quality, or `-b:v` which takes a bitrate value in bits.

You can also add an audio file:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 12 -i img%d.png -i audio.wav -shortest -r 25 v.mpg
```

By default the audio encoder `mp2` will be selected for this output format. Using `-shortest` will result in an output duration that is the same as the shortest input duration.

Comment: Hello, In this example you posted with audio.wav, where do I put the "image2" parameter? Also, will it be possible to use the length of the audio as length of entire video, and automatically fit all images accordingly, like, audio starts, 1st pic starts, audio ends on last picture.

Comment: @jeet You generally don't need `-f image2`, and I updated the last example with the `-shortest` option.

Comment: Hi, I tried the latest command you posted above, but it gives me an error. I've updated the post above. Can I not use the bitrates etc, and just fit all images according to the length of the audio?

Comment: It looks like as if rate is not the problem. I removed the audio file from input parameters and it starts making the video. What can I do to include the audio as well, possibly in the same command?